# Cannot set property 'locale' of undefined, not working in replit but at my pc

Tags: node.js, express, discord, discord.js

I get this error on replit but on my pc the bot works well, but i want to host my bot free 24/7.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETlqm.png)

[This is my i18n configure in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iogQ.png)

If there is an other website where i can paste my code and host it with express it would also help me.
thx

Answer (score 0):

Repl.it is just not reading the sub-prototype 'locale' from your `targetObject` you should just try switching hosts :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). It's free and you can get **550-1,000** hours of runtime for 0$. Probably the best feature of this hoster is the **GitHub integration**, so you don't have to upload your bot's code manually, but can connect your GitHub to a project and choose from which branch you want the code.

You can also set it to **automatically update** your project on Heroku when you push to the selected branch.

Important note: If you host your bot on Heroku, for example, config.json cannot be used. Variables like the bot-token etc. must be set on heroku. The best thing to do is to watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFearuMjI4s), everything is explained there